# Find position of element in array of elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays representing the states of a list before and after being sorted:

```
var $before = $('li');
// SORTING
var $after = $('li');
```

Now I want to pick a specific item `var $item = $after.filter(':first-child')` and find the position it had in the $before list. What I am doing so far works:

```
var beforeIndex = false;

$.each($before, function(i, v) {

  if($(v)[0] == $item[0]) {

    beforeIndex = i;

  }

})
```

However, I feel like there should be a simpler solution, something like:

```
$before.find(x => $(x)[0] == $item[0]);
```

(which doesn't work). Any ideas? :)

Comment: If `$before` is a jQuery object (it is) use `$before.each()` rather than `$.each($before..)`  `$.each()` is intended to be used with non-jQuery objects.

Comment: Also `$(x)[0]` is pointless

Comment: Why don't you just set a data attribute on each?

Comment: There's also the `$before.index($item)` that is available to get the index of an element in a result stack.

Comment: @Taplar TIL [.index](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index). That's a good one. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this as below. I tried to use a minimal example.

```js
var $li = $("ul > li");
var $item = $li.filter(':last-child');

var result = Array.prototype.findIndex.call($li, (li) => {
  return $item.is($(li));
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a data attribute, than there is no looking it up.

```js
// Loop over the lis and set a data attribute with the index
$("li").each(function (index) {
  $(this).data("orginalIndex", index)
})

// some random sort code to change the order
$("ul").append($("li").sort(function(){
  return Math.random() > .5 ? 1 : -1
}))

// loop over the newly sorted lis and read the text and old index
$("li").each(function () {
  var elem = $(this);
  console.log(elem.text(), elem.data("orginalIndex"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```